# Spring Data (REST) & @Query: optional list as param

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-rest

I'm having the following function in one of my repositories:

```
@RestResource(path = "filter", rel = "filter")
@Query("SELECT t "
        + "FROM Trip t "
        + "WHERE "
        + "(:from IS NULL OR t.startTs >= :from) "
        + "AND (:categories IS NULL OR t.category IN :categories) ")
Page<Trip> filter(
        @Param("from") Instant from,
        @Param("categories") List<Category> categories,
        Pageable pageable);
```

The `Category` is an enum which is stored as:

```
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
```

in the `Trips` table.

When I'm doing my HTTP request with exactly one category I'm getting the correct results. Same behaviour when doing a request without categories key.

`htt*://localhost/filter?categories=PRIVATE` ==> ok

`htt*://localhost/filter` ==> ok

When using more than one category:

```
htt*://localhost/filter?categories=PRIVATE,BUSINESS
```

I'm getting the following exception:

> org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected AST
>   node: {vector} [select count(t) FROM foo.bar.services.trips.model.Trip
>   t WHERE (:from IS NULL OR t.startTs >= :from) AND (:categories_0_,
>   :categories_1_ IS NULL OR t.category IN (:categories_0_,
>   :categories_1_)) ]

Anybody have an idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try one of the following:

**1)** Try to enclose the statements involving the list in parentheses:

```
@Query("SELECT t "
        + "FROM Trip t "
        + "WHERE "
        + "(:from IS NULL OR t.startTs >= :from) "
        + "AND ((:categories IS NULL) OR (t.category IN :categories)) ")
```

**2)** Enclose the :categories in parentheses here

```
t.category IN (:categories)
```

Comment: Tried both but weren't working. But you pointed me to the right direction. This is what finally is working: AND ((:categories) IS NULL OR (t.category IN (:categories)). Thx!

Comment: Great! Glad i could help